# Asterisk selector with parcel

Tags: css, parcel

When I try to use Asterik selector, I get the next error:

> @parcel/transformer-css: Unexpected token Delim('*')

This is the css block:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
  }
```

The parcel version:

> "parcel": "^2.8.3"

After trying a lot of things, if I add a blank line at the beginning of the CSS file, Parcel builts fine. I don´t understand it.

[image]